# Get Dependency Property Value in UserControl Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF. I'm facing the following issue. I have a User Control, Here is the Code of User Control

**CustomControl Code**

```
public partial class CustomCanvas : UserControl
{
    public CustomCanvas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DrawCanvas();
    }

    private void DrawCanvas()
    {
        //TODO:
        //Get the Dictionary Value from Parent Bound Property
    }

    public Dictionary<string, List<Shapes>> ShapesData
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<string, List<Shapes>>)GetValue(ShapesDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShapesDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShapesDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShapesData", typeof(Dictionary<string, List<Shapes>>), typeof(CustomCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(ShapesDataChanged));

    private static void ShapesDataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var value = e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

**Main Window Code**

```
<Grid>
    <uc:CustomCanvas ShapesData="{Binding ShData}" ></uc:CustomCanvas>
</Grid>
```

Value of ShapesData is bounded to following code.

```
ShData = new Dictionary<string, List<Shapes>>()
        {
            {"Week 1", new List<Shapes>() {Shapes.Circle, Shapes.Rectangle}},
            {"Week 2", new List<Shapes>() {Shapes.Circle}},
            {"Week 3", new List<Shapes>() {Shapes.Rectangle}}
        };
```

Now My question is that in CustomControl **DrawCanvas** Method i want to fetch the bounded value in parent. Could any one guide me regarding that.

**P.S**: I know how to bound this value in child using relative RelativeSource and Mode as FindAncestor. Here i want to just fetch the value and process that Dictionary data. In **ShapesDataChanged** i can easily access the data but the issue is in fetching it in DrawCanvas Function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should simply use the `ShapesData` property. It will return bound value.

Comment: @ghord that's what i thought initially. But unfortunately it didn't work, I don't understand why it's not working as it's quite logical.

Comment: Got the answer. @ghord you were right. The issue was that i wasn't calling the DrawCanvase on the change of dependency property change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DependencyObject's GetValue() method.

```
var theValueYouNeeded = CustomCanvas.GetValue(ShapesDataProperty);
Dictionary<string, List<Shapes>> value = (Dictionary<string, List<Shapes>>)theValueYouNeeded;
....
```